# Python for loop syntax error

Tags: python, centos

There seems to be a syntax error at the for loop but I don't know why. I'm somewhat new to Python, and I'm trying this in Centos.

```
fil = open('acnt_data_text.txt', 'r')
for data_str in fil:
    result = subprocess.call(["php", "class.php"], data_str)

print result

fil.close()
```

SyntaxError: `invalid syntax: for data_str in fil:`

Comment: Make sure in your code that this line `result = subprocess.call(["php", "class.php"], data_str)` is inside your for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be spaced like this

```
fil = open('acnt_data_text.txt', 'r')
for data_str in fil: 
   result = subprocess.call(["php", "class.php"], data_str)
print result

fil.close()
```

You can avoid closing the file if you use `with` instead like so

```
with open('acnt_data_text.txt', 'r') as fil:
    for data_str in fil: 
       result = subprocess.call(["php", "class.php"], data_str)
    print result
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have the stuff after the colon (`result = subprocess.call etc...`) on another line, so it's easier to read. Also, this might fix the syntax error.