# I was having a syntax error with a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax-error

So first of all, in my research, I came across [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024165/python-for-loop-syntax-error) It sounded like the exact problem I was having, so I tried out the method suggested in the answers. I am trying to use a k-Nearest-Neighbor algorithm with the following code:

```
train_data_copy['distance_to_new'] = numpy.sqrt(
    0
    for k in predictors:
        +(new_example[k]-train_data_copy[k])**2
```

where predictors is an array of variables in my dataset.

This was the last two lines after I changed the spacing:

```
for k in predictors:
   +(new_example[k]-train_data_copy[k])**2
```

I've also tried:

```
for k in predictors[]:
   +(new_example[k]-train_data_copy[k])**2
```

The error message was:

```
File "<ipython-input-27-a08c65d44488>", line 7
for k in predictors:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help. I have to finish this project soon.

EDIT: I already calculated the mean. I am trying to figure out the distance away from the mean each specific variable is, so that I can figure out how far from the overall mean a specific data point is.

EDIT 2: I managed to solve the problem on my own by simply writing out all the variables manually. I was just hoping there would be a faster way to do it.

Comment: To clarify why I named it what I did, I tried many different descriptive titles but the site kept rejecting them. The actual title is what's in quotes.

Comment: I know Python has been called "executable pseudocode", but Python cannot read between the lines like a human can. It's a precise technical language with precise meaning and it must be correctly structured to be executable. The code here shows a lack of understanding of the very basics. Might I suggest starting with a beginner textbook rather than expecting us to write one for you? Maybe Byte of Python?

Answer (score 1):

Python distinguishes statements (instructions) from expressions (things that evaluate to a value). You cannot use a `for` statement in an expression context (like an argument to the sqrt function) because it does not evaluate to anything, not even `None`. This is the cause of the syntax error.

You also have not balanced your parentheses.

It is not clear from your code what you even mean to do. Perhaps you meant to use a comprehension instead?

Comment: I balanced the parentheses later in the code. I just didn't bother copy-pasting that line.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a block within a function call. Use a [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) instead.

```
train_data_copy['distance_to_new'] = numpy.sqrt(
   [(new_example[k] - train_data_copy[k])**2 for k in predictors]
)
```

This turns out to be essentially

```
train_data_copy['distance_to_new'] = [(new_example[k] - train_data_copy[k]) for k in predictors]
```

since `**2` is neutralised by `numpy.sqrt()`. However, your code in the first snippet suggests that you're wanting to sum all the numbers first. You can do this using the `sum` function.

```
train_data_copy['distance_to_new'] = sum((new_example[k]-train_data_copy[k])**2 for k in predictors)
```